# Is there a clever way to determine the length of Java bytecode instructions?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-bytecode

I'm creating a static analysis tool for Java, and there's some information about the programs I'm analyzing that will be easier to get if I can get it from the bytecode in `.class` files.

I don't care about every single one the [instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings) that might be in the class file. E.g., I might only need to see if there are any `getfield` instructions.

The problem is that since each instruction has a variable length, it seems that in the general case, I need to (in my code) specify the length of every single opcode before I can determine where the (e.g.) `getfield` instructions start and end.

For some other instruction sets (like [x86](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html)), there are rules like "any opcode below 0x0F is 1 byte, anything equal to or greater than 0x0F is two bytes."

Is there any convenient pattern like this in the Java bytecode instructions?

Comment: Even if there is no pattern (and there are some varadic opcodes) you want to write a static analysis tool and don't want to, worst case, make a mapping table of << 256 opcodes. Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you try to map instruction op codes to instruction sizes, you’ll get the following discouraging table:

```
0 - 15       1 bytes
16           2 bytes
17           3 bytes
18           2 bytes
19 - 20      3 bytes
21 - 25      2 bytes
26 - 53      1 bytes
54 - 58      2 bytes
59 - 131     1 bytes
132          3 bytes
133 - 152    1 bytes
153 - 168    3 bytes
169          2 bytes
170 - 171    special handling
172 - 177    1 bytes
178 - 184    3 bytes
185 - 186    5 bytes
187          3 bytes
188          2 bytes
189          3 bytes
190 - 191    1 bytes
192 - 193    3 bytes
194 - 195    1 bytes
196          special handling
197          4 bytes
198 - 199    3 bytes
200 - 201    5 bytes
```

In other words, there is no size information encoded in the instruction’s numeric value nor its bit pattern, but there is another property, which you can consider some sort of pattern: out of the ~200 defined instructions, roughly 150 instructions have the size of one byte, leaving only ~50 instructions which require any handling at all. Even this small group of instructions can be subdivided further into logical groups, the majority taking three bytes, the second biggest group taking two bytes.

So the code of a method rushing through the instructions may look like:

```
static void readByteCode(ByteBuffer bb) {
    while(bb.hasRemaining()) {
        switch(bb.get()&0xff) {
            case BIPUSH: // one byte embedded constant
            case LDC:    // one byte embedded constant pool index
            // follow-up: one byte embedded local variable index
            case ILOAD:  case LLOAD:  case FLOAD:  case DLOAD:  case ALOAD:
            case ISTORE: case LSTORE: case FSTORE: case DSTORE: case ASTORE: case RET:
            case NEWARRAY: // one byte embedded array type
                bb.get();
                break;

            case IINC: // one byte local variable index, another one for the constant
            case SIPUSH: // two bytes embedded constant
            case LDC_W: case LDC2_W: // two bytes embedded constant pool index
            // follow-up: two bytes embedded branch offset
            case IFEQ: case IFNE: case IFLT: case IFGE: case IFGT: case IFLE:
            case IF_ICMPEQ: case IF_ICMPNE: case IF_ICMPLT: case IF_ICMPGE:
            case IF_ICMPGT: case IF_ICMPLE: case IF_ACMPEQ: case IF_ACMPNE:
            case GOTO: case JSR: case IFNULL: case IFNONNULL:
            // follow-up: two bytes embedded constant pool index to member or type
            case GETSTATIC: case PUTSTATIC: case GETFIELD: case PUTFIELD:
            case INVOKEVIRTUAL: case INVOKESPECIAL: case INVOKESTATIC: case NEW:
            case ANEWARRAY: case CHECKCAST: case INSTANCEOF:
                bb.getShort();
                break;

            case MULTIANEWARRAY:// two bytes pool index, one byte dimension
                bb.getShort();
                bb.get();
                break;

            // follow-up: two bytes embedded constant pool index to member, two reserved
            case INVOKEINTERFACE: case INVOKEDYNAMIC:
                bb.getShort();
                bb.getShort();
                break;

            case GOTO_W: case JSR_W:// four bytes embedded branch offset
                bb.getInt();
                break;

            case LOOKUPSWITCH:
                // special handling left as an exercise for the reader...
                break;
            case TABLESWITCH:
                // special handling left as an exercise for the reader...
                break;
            case WIDE:
                int widened=bb.get()&0xff;
                bb.getShort(); // local variable index
                if(widened==IINC) {
                    bb.getShort(); // constant offset value
                }
                break;
            default: // one of the ~150 instructions taking one byte
        }
    }
}
```

I intentionally kept some of the instructions separated having the same number of follow-up bytes, but with a different meaning. After all, you want to insert some actual logic at certain places, I guess.

Note that the handling of the two `switch` bytecode instructions is left out, they require padding whose implementation requires knowledge about the code alignment within the buffer, which is in control of the caller. So that’s up to your specific application. Refer to the documentation of [`lookupswitch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.lookupswitch) and [`tableswitch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.tableswitch).

Of course, handling of all single byte instructions as `default` implies that the code won’t catch unknown or invalid instructions. If you want safety, you’ll have to insert the cases…

Answer (score 1):

[The JVM spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.11) is fairly clear about the instruction set:

> The number and size of the operands are determined by the opcode.

You could try to leverage an existing bytecode library, such as Apache Commons BCEL, and use the metadata about opcodes defined there to build a separate data structure for your app.  For example, [it contains a `GETFIELD` class](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/generic/GETFIELD.html) along with a `getLength()` method that represents the JVM instruction.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such feature in the bytecode design. The opcodes are simply [grouped](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-7.html) by their meaning. JVM implementations I've seen use table lookup for the bytecode length, with the special handling of [`wide`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.wide), [`tableswitch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.tableswitch) and [`lookupswitch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.lookupswitch) bytecodes.

[Such table](https://gist.github.com/apangin/524391f92082eaaf611e7ec1607fd1dc) is pretty small: there are only 202 bytecodes.

**Note** that the length depends not only on the opcode itself, but also on the **position** of the bytecode: `tableswitch` and `lookupswitch` have variable length padding due to alignment requirements.