# How do virtual machines like Lua or JVM represent (and work on) larger data types?

Tags: c, bytecode, vm-implementation

Currently working on a toy virtual machine with its own assembly language modelled after ARM, so I'm working towards getting something like this working:

```
// adds the r1 and r2 registers, result goes in r0
add r0, r1, r2
```

Here's my idea of a 64-bit bytecode representation I'm considering using for instructions:

```
// 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
//  ^ inst    ^ reg      ^------^ op       ^------^ op       ^------^ op
```

So using the example above, it would be 8-bits for the instruction `add`, 8-bits for the destination register `r0`, and 16-bits each for up to three operands (registers, literals, etc).

But then I got to thinking: this works fine for integers but how would an instruction that adds two 32-bit floats work? There isn't enough space in the instruction to store the floats plus the instruction and destination register. I'm developing my VM in C and as far as I know 16 or 24-bit floats aren't a thing.

Does anyone have any insights on how other VMs tackle this issue?

Comment: In the case of the JVM, "out of bounds" constants are referenced by a separate constant pool data structure. Because the JVM uses an operand stack, it doesn't really look like ARM or any other RISC instructions set. Perhaps in your case you'd have a special instruction to reference a constant pool? Or perhaps introduce "wide" variants that are 128 bits, etc.

Comment: Perhaps you just need to be selective about what operations can be performed.  For example, maybe you can support only register and indirect addressing for floating point operands.

Answer (score 1):

When you say, your architecture is “modelled after ARM”, you mean, it’s using three explicitly encoded operands and a fixed instruction size.

You couldn’t be farther away from the JVM’s bytecode format. The JVM uses a variable instruction size and the instructions are not even grouped in a way that would make it easy to recognize the size of an instruction, as discussed in [Is there a clever way to determine the length of Java bytecode instructions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38032729/2711488) A bytecode processor simply has to know all the instructions and their sizes.

Further, the bytecode uses an operand stack, rather than explicitly encoded operands. The instruction to add two `double` values, `dadd`, consists of a single byte opcode only. It’s defined to pop two values from the operand stack, add them, and push the result back. Which means, the preceding instructions determine the actual source of the arguments and the following instruction will determine where to store the result, as discussed in [What is the role of operand stack in JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61302770/2711488)

This provides a great flexibility. The preceding instructions might have pushed the contents of local variables, closest equivalent to address CPU registers, but they also could have pushed constant values instead. For both options, there are optimized variants. The linked Q&A names the different variants to address local variables or load `int` constants. For `double` constants, there are single byte instructions, [`dconst_0` and `dconst_1`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se16/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.dconst_d), to push the common values zero or one. But you could also use the three byte sequence [`bipush 100`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se16/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.bipush), [`i2d`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se16/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.i2d) to encode the value `100.0`, for example, which is still more compact than encoding the eight byte value `100.0` directly. Finally, for arbitrary values, the instruction [`ldc2_w`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se16/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.ldc2_w) can be used to load them from the [constant pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se16/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4) of a class.

Besides constants or values of a variable, the addressing via operand stack allows to directly use the result of a previous calculation. Technically, the `bipush 100`, `i2d` example did already use the opportunity. But the Q&A linked above discusses an example of a more complex calculation.

---

If you keep modelling your instruction set after ARM, it would be more useful to look how ARM software has to use embedded constants, rather than looking at a JVM.